# Disable Autorotation from subviews when applying CFAffineTransformRotation to parent view in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Let Consider that In ViewController, I have one view and 5 buttons which is subview of that view.My problem is that when I am applying CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated to View its is rotating perfect as how I expect.but that 5 buttons also rotating towards that, I don't want to rotate the buttons.can anyone tell me, I want that button should not be rotate towards parent view.
I applied opposite angle to buttons, but the button size is getting resize.

```
    UIViewController(portrait mode)
         UIView(should rotate)
            button1(shouldn't rotate)
            button2(shouldn't rotate).......
            button5(shouldn't rotate)

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading heading: CLHeading) {


      let maxLat: Double = fmax(userLocation.latitude,  userLocation.latitude)
        let maxLon: Double = fmax(userLocation.longitude, userLocation.longitude)
        let minLat: Double = fmin(userLocation.latitude,  userLocation.latitude)
        let minLon: Double = fmin(userLocation.longitude, userLocation.longitude)
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((maxLat + minLat) / 2, (maxLon + minLon) / 2)
        angle2U = getBearing(toPoint: center, longitude: userLocation.longitude, latitude: userLocation.latitude)
        let direction2G = CGFloat(heading.magneticHeading * Double.pi/180)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let direction2GN = CGFloat(self.angle2U) - direction2G
            let final_transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: direction2GN)
            self.compass_view.transform = final_transform
            self.optionbutton1.transform = compass_view.transform.inverted()
self.option_button2.transform = compass_view.transform.inverted()
self.option_button3.transform = compass_view.transform.inverted()
self.option_button4.transform = compass_view.transform.inverted()
self.option_button5.transform = compass_view.transform.inverted()

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rotate buttons back.

You can use [inverted()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455264-inverted) for that. For example:

```
let transform = // your CGAffineTransform
view.transform = transform 
button1.transform = transform.inverted()
...
button5.transform = transform.inverted()
```

Or:

```
button1.transform = yourRotatedView.transform.inverted()
...
button5.transform = yourRotatedView.transform.inverted()
```

Comment: thanks for ur response, I already tried this, but button size is getting shrink, I don't know  the reason why??

Comment: What do you mean? Could you add screenshots or code?

View rotating rotates all subviews too. And coordinates of subviews changes accordingly. After rotating buttons will be in another places.

Comment: Do you want the buttons to be in the same place as before the rotation?

Sizes aren't changed after inverted(), but the buttons have a new coordinates on the screen because their superview was rotated.

Comment: yeah, u right, but I don't know how to solve that issue.I want the width and height should be fixed.

Comment: The easiest solution is to move the buttons to the top view. Then the rotating won't change the buttons.

Comment: I am telling you should add the buttons to superview of compass_view. Then transform will rotate the only compass_view.

Comment: How did you create/add your buttons? Storyboard or programmatically?

Programmatically:
`compass_view.superview?.addSubview(button)`

Comment: I don't to add the buttons to any of the views subview, expect compass_view. that's why I am stucking here.

Comment: Could you add code how you create and add compass_view and buttons?